# How to integrate Ionic framework in an existing Angular application with custom webpack configuration?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack

I am setting up a build process for Angular 8 and Ionic 4 using webpack. How do i fully integrate Ionic 4 in my application using a completely custom webpack configuration?

We are rewriting an existing Cordova 8 and AngularJS 1.4.9 hybrid mobile application to run modern Angular 8 and legacy AngularJS code in parallel. Using a completely custom webpack configuration we were able to bundle everything together (including the node_modules) and run it on mobile devices.

That being said: Custom Angular 8 component styles and HTML templates are fully integrated in the bundle and apply to the components.

Now we are trying to integrate Ionic 4 components into the Angular 8 application using the webpack build process. We are also able to bundle the Ionic 4 components into the vendor.js file.

The only thing still missing are the CSS styles and Ionic won't apply them to the components. I figured out that Ionic needs to run some JavaScript-snippet to fully apply all styles to its components. Nothing happened trying to integrate the Ionic 4 web components JavaScript code.

The following code shows our current webpack configuration using the angular compiler plugin from @ngtools/webpack module:

```
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    runtimeChunk: { name: 'runtime' },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /node_modules/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  entry: {
    'main': './src/main.ts'
  },
  output: { filename: '../app/_bundles/[name].js' },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['node_modules']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: ['html-loader'] },
      { test: /\.(css|scss)$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'], include: [/node_modules/] },
      { test: /\.(css|scss)$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'], exclude: [/node_modules/] }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({ failOnError: false, cwd: process.cwd() }),
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({ tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json', entryModule: './src/app/app.module#AppModule', sourceMap: true })
  ]
};
```

These are all AngularJS, Angular and Ionic modules used in our project:

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^8.2.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.8.1",
    ...
```